# Create a python dictionary from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary from a list in python. I'm creating  alist from a .txt fril in the same directory as the .py file. But I don't understand how I create a dictionary without manually assigning a key to every value?

```
l = open ("Luther_King.txt").read()
words = l.split( )
print (words)
```

The print statement is just to check if it did in fact split the string into a list. Am I going to need to manually assign a key for every word or can I generate one somehow?

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: OK, you've a list of words and you want to create a dictionary out of this list. What do you want the keys and values to be? Each word in the list a key or value?

Comment: For a dict, you need (key, value) pairs. Were would they be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have to have key and value. You can try this, send two list and merge them in a dictionary. You can just send a very basic list in order to have a key like : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...

```
def get_dic_from_two_lists(keys, values):
    return {keys[i]: values[i] for i in range(keys)}
```

Comment: How about `dict(zip(keys, values))`?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a wild guess- and suggest you use **range** of the size of your list to generate keys.Then **zip** them together,you'll have your dictionary!!

```
#Your original list
['Jack', 'Luther', 'Dima', 'Vijay']

#Generate another list,which will be your keys
key_list=range(1,5,1)

newdict = dict(zip(key_list, words))

#This is how new dict would look
{1: 'Jack', 2: 'Luther', 3: 'Dima', 4: 'Vijay'}
```